# Ubuntu Server Not Accepting External Connections

Tags: ubuntu, tcp

I have an Ubuntu 14.04.4 ("trusty") server that is running Apache (port 80), some custom Nodejs scripts (ports 8081 and 8082), and Mongodb (port 27017). One week ago I was testing with external applications (Amazon Echo) and all the connections were fine. When I came back to it today, no service running on the server will accept connections that originate off my network.

Here's my tcpdump **taken on the target server** for a Mongodb connection originating on the local network (different host, same network). Again, the connection works fine:

```
$ sudo tcpdump -i p3p1 -vv port 27017
tcpdump: listening on p3p1, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes

20:39:15.435562 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 128, id 19216, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    10.0.0.22.6611 > cloud.27017: Flags [S], cksum 0x76ad (correct), seq 646322774, win 8192, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 2,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0

20:39:15.435593 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    cloud.27017 > 10.0.0.22.6611: Flags [S.], cksum 0xbaf1 (correct), seq 2557202729, ack 646322775, win 29200, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK,nop,wscale 7], length 0

20:39:15.435726 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 128, id 19217, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    10.0.0.22.6611 > cloud.27017: Flags [.], cksum 0x2dab (correct), seq 1, ack 1, win 16425, length 0
```

Here's what it looks like for a request originating outside the local network:

```
20:43:16.537658 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 235, id 7014, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    ec2-54-87-205-153.compute-1.amazonaws.com.49742 > cloud.27017: Flags [S], cksum 0xa06d (correct), seq 520219032, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 455422 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0

20:43:17.527219 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 235, id 7015, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    ec2-54-87-205-153.compute-1.amazonaws.com.49742 > cloud.27017: Flags [S], cksum 0x9f73 (correct), seq 520219032, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 455672 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
```

I've checked the iptables and got this response:

```
$ sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

I'm a developer, not a very accomplished sysadmin. I've worn Google out on this and I don't have any idea where to look next. **If you have any ideas what I should try next, please let me know.**

Comment: You are running on Amazon EC2, so please log into the AWS console and check your security group (firewall settings) for this server. Also check how your VPC (Virtual Private Cloud is setup). Maybe this is subnet or routing. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Networking.html

Comment: The server is running at my house. The off network connection request illustrated above originated from an Amazon Lambda server. The examples above were meant to illustrate that requests **originating from the local network** are being logged by tcpdump and forwarded to the listening application and requests **originating elsewhere**, e.g. Amazon hosts, are also logged by tcpdump but are not being forwarded to the listening applications. I surmised from the fact that tcpdump logs the incoming connection request that routing issues were not the problem.

Comment: This is a networking question, not a programming question, and therefore it's off-topic here. You may be able to get help at [sf] (check their guidelines first), [ubuntu.se] or [su] instead. The guidelines for this site are in our [help].